Datagrid Width WinUI 3
I'm new into WinUI 3 and I'm doing a datagrid to show a list of products and I want to make the datagrid columns fill the datagrid when total width is not the full datagri width but to show a horizontal scroll if the total width of the columns exceed grid width.
My grid xaml code right now is this one:
 <Grid x:Name="ContainerGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="TableGrid" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,30,10,10" CornerRadius="5">
        <controls:DataGrid x:Name="MainDataGrid" LoadingRow="ColorRow" 
                           GridLinesVisibility="All" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=TableGrid}" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FrozenColumnCount="2"
                           Visibility="Visible">
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="Auto">
                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox 
                                IsChecked="{Binding Import}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                                Width="20" Height="20" MinHeight="20" MinWidth="20"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Foto" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Foto}" Width="100" Height="115" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Modelo" Binding="{Binding Modelo}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Código de Estilo" Binding="{Binding Codigo_Estilo}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Color" Binding="{Binding Color}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Descripción de Color" Binding="{Binding Descripcion_Color}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Talla" Binding="{Binding Talla}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Talla EU" Binding="{Binding Talla_EU}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Ancho" Binding="{Binding Ancho}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="EAN" Binding="{Binding EAN}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="SKU" Binding="{Binding SKU}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Stock" Binding="{Binding Cantidad_Disponible}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Stock Avelon" Binding="{Binding Avelon_Stock}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Familia" Binding="{Binding Familia}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <!--<controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Uso" Binding="{Binding Uso}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>-->
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Categoría" Binding="{Binding Categoria}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Temporada" Binding="{Binding Temporada}" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="País" Binding="{Binding Pais}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlock}"/>
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>

        </controls:DataGrid>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="225" Height="Auto" Margin="0,40,15,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <ComboBox x:Name="Brand_Selector" PlaceholderText="Selecciona una marca" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" SelectionChanged="ChangeBrand">
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="NB" Width="225" IsSelected="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image Source="Assets/NB Text.png" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="FLUCHOS" IsSelected="False" Width="225">
                    <Image Source="Assets/fluchos.png" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="TIMBERLAND" IsSelected="False" Width="225">
                    <Image Source="Assets/Timberland-logo.png" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
            <models:ButtonCustom Height="41" x:Name="SyncButton" Content="Sincronizar" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Click="SyncButton_Click">
                <Button.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Button.RenderTransform>
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Resources>
            </models:ButtonCustom>
            <models:ButtonCustom Height="41" x:Name="OrdersButton" Content="Pedidos" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Click="OrdersButton_Click">
                <Button.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Button.RenderTransform>
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Resources>
            </models:ButtonCustom>
            <TextBlock Text="Fecha disponibilidad" FontSize="20pt" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <DatePicker x:Name="disponbilidadSelect" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Stock mínimo" FontSize="20pt" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <NumberBox x:Name="MinimumStock" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" Text="20"></NumberBox>
            <Expander Header="Estados" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="pendant" Content="Pendientes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" IsChecked="true"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="imported" Content="Ya importados" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="descarted" Content="Descartados" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander>
            <StackPanel x:Name="NB_Options">
                <Expander Header="Tamaños" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="NB_Size_Options">
                        <CheckBox x:Name="M" Content="M" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" IsChecked="true"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="B" Content="B" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" IsChecked="true"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="D" Content="D" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" IsChecked="true"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="W" Content="W" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" IsChecked="true"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="O" Content="Otros" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="Fluchos_Options" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Expander Header="Temporada" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="season_stack_panel">
                        <CheckBox x:Name="spring" Content="Primavera" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" IsChecked="true"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="summer" Content="Verano" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="autum" Content="Otoño" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="winter" Content="Invierno" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander>
                <Expander Header="Año" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="year_stack_panel">
                        <CheckBox x:Name="last_year" Content="2024" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" IsChecked="true"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="this_year" Content="2025" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="next_year" Content="2026" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <models:ButtonCustom Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SaveButton" Content="Importar" Padding="10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="1,0">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
        </models:ButtonCustom>
    </Grid>

    
    <Grid x:Name="LoadingRing" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ProgressRing 
        Width="350" 
        Height="350"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

If I set Width="*" to last column when total width exceed the datagrid width it wont show horizontal scroll and instead it will shrink last column to nothing
Can anyone help me?
Edit: I forgot to mention. I'm using CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.DataGrid

Setting the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to Auto or Visible should help.
UPDATE
In your case, you should set the MinWidth for each column (or at least one of them).
For example:
<controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Item1" MinWidth="100" .../>
<controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Item2" MinWidth="100" .../>
<controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Item3" Width="*" MinWidth="100" .../>


Thanks for the response. It still shrinks the columns if Width="*" is set and total width exceed end of grid and adds a last empty column instead of stretching the columns if Width="Auto" is set and total width doesn't exceed and of grid

I updated my answer. Can you try setting the MinWidth?

So everything to Width="Auto" and MinWidth=100? But it's not responsibe doing like this right? I mean, If I set MinWith=100 to everything in 1080p screen it fits right but not in 2K screen. When set into 2K with Width="Auto" and MinWidth=100 set then the last empty columns is added to fill the DataGrid

Okey so with that you said I did a little bit of trickery and made a function that changes the MinWidth of each column to MainDataGrid.Width/NumberOfVisibleColumns and set it to Window SizeChanged event and it seems to work. I'm open to any other sugestions since I guess this is not the right way of achieving what I want to do

If you want the last column to fill the space (if any), set it as Width="*" as you first suggested.

I created a sample app to confirm my answer and it works.

If I do this, when text in other columns exceed datagrid width then instead of showing the horizontal scroll bar it will shrink the column with Width="*" attribute.
Edit: Yeah, seems to work fine if Width="*" and MinWidth="*" is set to last column! I'll mark your response as answer. It would be nice if you edit it to reflect the Width="*" in the last column too

The code in my answer does set Width="*" on the last column.
